# How do i cross compile at cmake with nvcc

Tags: linux, cmake, cross-compiling, nvcc

Here I want to cross compile on an Linux x64 machine some cuda code with cmake:

```
> # CMakeLists.txt to build hellocuda.cu 
>cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8) 
>find_package(CUDA QUIET REQUIRED)
> 
> # this one is important 
>SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux) 
>set( CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm )
> 
> # specify the cross compiler 
>SET (CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc ) 
>SET (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ )
> 
> # where is the target environment  
>SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH  /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin )
> 
> # search for programs in the build host directories
>SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
> # for libraries and headers in the target directories
>SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
> SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
> 
> #make build verbose 
>SET (CUDA_VERBOSE_BUILD ON CACHE BOOL "nvcc verbose" FORCE)
> 
> #make makefile verbose 
>SET ( CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE TRUE CACHE BOOL "verbose makefile" FORECE)
> 
> #target device is 32 bit 
>SET (CUDA_64_BIT_DEVICE_CODE OFF CACHE BOOL "device code" FORCE)
> 
> #use armhf c++ compiler 
>SET (CUDA_HOST_COMPILER "/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++" CACHE STRING "host compiler" FORCE)
> 
> # Pass options to NVCC
> #set( CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}; -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 )
> 
> # Specify binary name and source file to build it from
> cuda_add_executable( hellocuda src/hellocuda.cu )
```

But I do not understand how to tell the nvcc to compile for ARM

Comment: **-target-cpu-arch** option can be used I guess. For further information look at [Here](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi15/cse262-a/static/cuda-5.5-doc/pdf/CUDA_Compiler_Driver_NVCC.pdf)